# Does coveralls provide views coverage for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, code-coverage, coveralls

I can't find any documentation on what coveralls provides coverage reports for in Rails, and I need something for views coverage. Does coveralls provide views coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no coverage tools (coveralls, or gems like [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) & [rcov](https://github.com/relevance/rcov)) provides coverage for views.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it seemed like but I was hoping I was wrong. Thanks.